# How to change the height of the object by using DragGesture in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to increase the height of the shape by using the "dragger" (rounded grey rectangle) element. I use the `DragGesture` helper provided by SwiftUI to get the current position of the user finger. Unfortunately, during the drag event content is jumping for some reason.

Could you please help me to find the root cause of the problem?

This is how it looks during the drag event

[image]

If I remove `Spacer()` everything is okay but not what I wanted

[image]

This is my code snippets

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      CustomDraggableComponent()
      
      Spacer() // If comment this line the result will be as on the bottom GIF example
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

let MIN_HEIGHT = 50

struct CustomDraggableComponent: View {
  @State var height: CGFloat = MIN_HEIGHT
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: .infinity, height: height)
      
      HStack {
        Spacer()
        Rectangle()
          .fill(Color.gray)
          .frame(width: 100, height: 10)
          .cornerRadius(10)
          .gesture(
            DragGesture()
              .onChanged { value in
                height = value.translation.height + MIN_HEIGHT
              }
          )
        Spacer()
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct calculation is

```
.gesture(
    DragGesture()
        .onChanged { value in
            height = max(MIN_HEIGHT, height + value.translation.height)
        }
)
```

Also, remove the infinite width. It's invalid.

```
.frame(minHeight: 0, maxHeight: height)

or 

.frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: height)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in `height` property. I miscalculated

Comment: I also want to implement similar functionality. Pls tell what u change to fix.